# Jmeter with Selenium runs scenario Sequentially and not paralelly

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have a Junit Framework where in we have written the methods using Java/Selenium ( which occasionally we use for regression testing as well). Same methods we are mapping it to JMX file and then triggering the Jmeter to test our performance tests. all the methods have @Test annotation for Jmeter to detect.

I am launching Jmeter through command prompt with command

```
jmeter.bat -n -t c:\dev\test.jmx -Jusers = 3
```

Jmeter launches 3 browsers, but operation on Browser will happen only when i bring the browser to focus, that is username will enter in Browser 1 if its in focus , similarly in Browser 2 if its in focus. If not in focus then its failing that method. How can i overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried with JSexecutor, getwindow handle etc, but none of these resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue got resolved once we started executing Chrome in headless mode. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved Selenium tests shouldn't require the browser to be in focus otherwise executing tests via [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/) or in [Headless mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/driving-headless-browser-testing-with-selenium-and-python) won't be possible.

So my expectation is that the problem is not connected with JMeter, it's rather about your Selenium Java code which is relying on the browser to be in focus, please review your code and ensure that you're only using [Selenium API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/overview-summary.html)  (or Java API) for any browser manipulations including:

- filling in forms
- uploading files
- downloading files
- etc.

For instance if you're using any [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class functions - these classes are a subject for refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes using selenium api only for all operations. I am not using Robot class and i have used threadlocal concept for chrome driver instances for multiple users.